# Why does popover-controller give a property-error?

Tags: objective-c, properties, uipopovercontroller

A popover-controller has been declared in an `.h` file. But it is giving me error on implementation.

The `.h`-file:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)   VFImagePickerController     *imagePicker;
@property (nonatomic, strong)   UIPopoverController         *popoverController;
@property (nonatomic, strong)   UINavigationController      *targetVC;
```

The `.m`-file:
[image: The error]

What causes the error and how can I fix it?

Comment: why have you commented out the line @synthesize ... ? uncomment and clean all targets and run your project again..

Comment: @RenoJones With modern Objective-C and the latest compiler, you don't need `@synthesize` anymore.

Comment: ah yeah, You're right, xcode 4.2+ I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uncomment the synthesize line and remove underscore to look like this: `@synthetize popoverController;`

And replace every _popoverController var name in your .m file to popoverController

Comment: Somehow it worked. I guess the default ivar is synthesized as _popovercontroller. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 12):

It appears that your class is a subclass of `UIViewController`. `UIViewController` has a private, undocumented ivar of `_popoverController`. Since you are trying to create an ivar in your class with the same name, you are getting an error.

The easiest thing to do is to rename your `popoverController` property to something different. Otherwise your app might get flagged for using a private API.

Answer (score 9):

This problem occurs because your superclass, UIViewController, already has an instance variable named `_popoverController`. As a result, neither the default synthesis nor your explicit (commented) `@synthesize` directive have access to the instance variable that they want to use to provide the `popoverController` property.

You can resolve this by either renaming your property, or explicitly synthesizing the property to use a different instance variable name:

```
// Either
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *localPopoverController
// Or
@synthesize popoverController = _localPopoverController;
```

(Also note that the "local" prefix isn't necessarily best practice for your property names or instance variables; take a second to consider your preferred naming convention and pick a property/instance variable name appropriately.)

Answer (score 0):

Do not name your instance variable (or property) popoverController.  As mentioned above UIViewController has an instance variable declared as _popoverController.  (Who knows why.)

It would be wise not to give your popover controller a generic name anyway, because, for example, if you decide to add more than one popover to a toolbar, you'll have to create more than one popover controller to accomplish this.

If you look at Apple's sample code, you can see how they do this:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Popovers/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010436

Check out the private properties section in DetailViewController.  There, you will see three controller objects and none with the generic name "popoverController”. That will cause problems.

Comment: I would love to know why the ivar "_popoverController" is declared in UIViewController.