# Why do I have error of "attempt to use instance variable in super class" when using editButtonItem in my Conroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I wrote following code in my `viewDidLoad` method.

> self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

Error told me that

> Property 'navigationItem' attempting to use instance variable
>   '_navigationItem' declared in super class 'UIViewController'

How to solve this error please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Noob properties error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15073778/noob-properties-error)

Comment: No need to vote down, my man.. I am just new here and if my score was low I probably not able to continue to ask and engage in this platform. And it is not duplicate because that old answer does not solve my trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just synthesis the property `navigationItem` and it will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

That's an odd error. I would suggest breaking it into pieces. First declare a local variable of type   UINavigationItem. Let's call it myNavItem. Assign self.navigationItem to myNavItem. Then create another local variable (myEditButton) and use it to get value of self.editButtonItem.

Finally, put the value myEditButton into  myNavItem.rightBarButtonItem (`myNavItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem`). That way when you get an error you'll be able to tell exactly which bit of code is generating it.

Comment: Can you post an update explaining how you fixed it, and either post your own answer and accept it, or accept my answer? It's SO etiquette to mark your question as resolved once you find an answer, and good form to provide details so the thread can help other people as well.